# azure devops service connection to apple without fastlane

Tags: ios, azure-devops, testflight, fastlane

For distributing our iOS app to TestFlight, it used to be that we could authorize our pipeline with just an account password, which was a one-time deal.  But now, Apple requires 2FA, and so now we need to use a fastlane session, which expires every month or so - inconvenient!  Is there a way to authorize our pipeline another way that doesn't expire so frequently?

Comment: Any updates? I'm looking for a similar solution, where I want to connect directly to the App Store Connect API. But I haven't found any documentation about this yet.

Comment: @JacobAhlberg, no update - we haven't found a solution yet.  Lately the devops team is taking higher priority work, but will return to this in a week or two.  That said, you could use Fastlane, but the token will expire every couple of months.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to authorize our pipeline another way that doesn't expire so frequently?

I am afraid there is no such out of way to authorize our pipeline another way that doesn't expire so frequently.

Most of the iOS Continuous Delivery pipelines has been set up using Fastlane tools and 2FA become mandatory for all account holder role (not admin) in the App Store Connect, so there is no clean solution at the moment to solve this issue but there might be some temporary hacks works in the future.

Besides, if you are the admin user then you don’t need to enable the 2FA. This confirm ed by the Apple Developer Relationship team:

- 2FA will be only applicable if you are the account holder role (not
  admin) in the App Store Connect.
- If you are an admin user then you don’t need to enable the 2FA

Tweet from Christopher Pickslay [here](https://twitter.com/cpickslay/status/1096525317655547904).

In addition, there are currently some blogs about how to remove Fastlane from iOS projects completely, you could check them for some helps:

[Five Options for iOS Continuous Delivery without Fastlane](https://medium.com/xcblog/five-options-for-ios-continuous-delivery-without-fastlane-2a32e05ddf3d)

[Keep using Fastlane with Apple's 2FA changes](https://drobinin.com/posts/keep-using-fastlane-with-apples-2fa-changes/)

Comment: Thanks, Leo.  We'll look into this, and report back.

Comment: @tele-bird, Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, would you please let me know the latest information about this issue?

Comment: No update yet, but I will report back after we work on it.  Timeline for us is before the fastlane session token expires again - probably 1-2 weeks.